# Returning a dataset from asmx file to windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, web-services, dataset, asmx

I want to retrieve data from a dataset inside a Web Service to my Windows Form and then send data from my windows form to the web service.

I defined a function that returns a dataset inside a class in **my asmx file:**

```
Public Class DataSetWebService

    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetUsers() As DataSet
        Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WebServiceTest;Integrated Security=SSPI")
        Dim cm As SqlCommand : Dim ds As New DataSet : Dim da As SqlDataAdapter : Dim str As String  
        Try
            str = "Select * from User_Table"
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()
            cm = New SqlCommand(str, cn)
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cm)
            da.Fill(ds)
            return ds
        Catch ex As SqlException
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

In my Windows Form, I wrote the code below:

```
  Dim ws As New UserService.DataSetWebService()
```

But it says "DataSetWebService() not defined"

Comment: where is UserService? maybe you need to define dataService insisde userservice.

Comment: I added a Service Reference earlier with a link to the Web Service and I called it UserService. It is now in my "Service References" folder inside the project.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut update the service reference and re build the project and try

Comment: have you tried to debugg, to test the connection?

Comment: @Damith That worked. So do I have to delete the Service reference everytime I modify it, then add it again? Thanks.

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao Debugging the web service then deleting it from my windows form "Service references" folder THEN adding it again did the trick. :)

Comment: You need to update the reference if you add new service method or if there is change in your service method signatures

Comment: @HelpASisterOut yeah!! :)

Comment: @Damith It still says "DataSetWebService()" is an undefined class. So I had to move the GetUsers() function to "Service.VB" file so it would finally work. But I want to leave it in the asmx and call it from there. Any idea how to do that and why it's not working? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your service method as **Shared**. like this

```
Public Shared Function GetUsers() As DataSet
```

And then "Add Web Reference" to your windows application.

Hope it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: it worked for the function, but does this work if I want to call a SUB from the asmx file?

Comment: But as per your posted code, you wanted to return dataset. You can't return anything, if you use subroutine.